# how do I count LANs and WANs given a network topology?

Tags: lan, wan

how do I count LANs and WANs given a network topology? The question is quite straightforward. I find it difficult to know when something is a LAN or when it isn't. Same goes for WAN.

Here's an example where I would like to count the LANs and WANs.

[image]

Comment: If your question has been answered, you should mark it as answered so it doesn't keep popping up as needing additional answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per wikipedia, LANs:

*"A local area network (LAN) is a computer network that interconnects computers within a limited area such as a home, school, computer laboratory, or office building, using network media.[1] The defining characteristics of LANs, in contrast to wide area networks (WANs), include their smaller geographic area, and non-inclusion of leased telecommunication lines."*

I would add that Cisco Academy describes LANs similar to the above but also as controlled by by a single organization (i.e. one business, one school, one government department).

and for WANs, wikipedia says:

*"A wide area network (WAN) is a network that covers a broad area (i.e., any telecommunications network that links across metropolitan, regional, national or international boundaries) using leased telecommunication lines."*

In practice you can usually identify WANs in diagrams by clouds or lightning bolt-like connections (WAN links).  LANs are then the groups of switches and end-user devices that separated by the WAN links.  Usually routers are used to separate LANs.  So for the given diagram, 2 LANs and one WAN (WAN implied by the WAN link).